# hadoop 1.1.2 installation on windows

Tags: hadoop, java-home

I am trying to install `hadoop 1.1.2` on window machine with `cygwin`.
From on-line videos and tutorials, I have set up all most everything.
Now problem is when i try to create folder with commands

```
cd /usr/local/hadoop-1.1.2/bin         --> this works proper and set proper path then
./hadoop dfs -mkdir input      --> when this execute i get error
```

in error i get issue related to `JAVA_HOME` path is not set proper also show me text like `/Java/jre7/bin/bin/java` which looks wrong path.

but i have set `JAVA_HOME` path properly its here,

[image]

I have set same path with `/bin` in `path` variable.
I don't know where i have made mistake.

**EDIT**
full Error

```
./hadoop: line 320: C:/Java/jre7/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
./hadoop: line 390: C:/Java/jre7/bin/bin/java: No such file or directory
./hadoop: line 390: exec: C:/Java/jre7/bin/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you copy past the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problems with its solution

**1.  JAVA PATH ISSUE**

first is `JAVA_PATH` issue

Note: Have to use `JDK` not `JRE`.
      For Hadoop try to use folder name without space

In Environment variable

> JAVA_HOME =  C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

In `path` variable add below code with othres with `;`sepration

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin

In `hadoop-env.sh` file (you can find this file from `C:\cygwin\usr\local\hadoop-1.1.2\conf` if you are using windows machine).

Note that, remove `#` from starting of line and USE `\\` twice in file

> export JAVA_HOME=C:\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_25

if everything OK with JAVA_PATH you can check from `CYGWIN` consol
try below code to get `javaPath` which `hadoop` will use

> echo $JAVA_HOME

here you will get java version path
also can set `JAVAPATH` from runtime,try below code on `CYGWIN` treminal

> export JAVA_HOME=C:/JAVA/Jdk1.7.0_25

**2. USER ISSUE**

first of all Note that when you start with `hadoop` installation use same `USER` for `MASTER` and `SALVE`.

If you have different user then have to generate one extra file with name `config`(without extension)

if your `MASTER's` machine name is `jubin-pc` and username is `jubinp` and `SLAVES` machine name is `trainees11` and username is `trainees`(have to do vice-verse for both)

config file(for MASTER) Location `C:\cygwin\home\jubinp\.ssh\`

```
Host trainees11
User trainees
```

config file(for SLAVE) Location `C:\cygwin\home\trainees\.ssh\`

```
Host jubin-pc
User jubinp
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Solution for hadoop-2.6.0 and early:**

1. Be sure that path to JDK does not contain backspaces.
   (my variant **C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25**)
2. Add **JAVA_HOME** to path

   - My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> Create 
     **JAVA_HOME

     C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25**
   - Add **;%JAVA_HOME%\bin** to system Path
     [image]
3. Open **hadoop-env.sh** 
   (It located in C:\hadoop-2.6.0\etc\hadoop for my hadoop-2.6.0)
   and add line **export JAVA_HOME=C:/Java/Jdk1.8.0_25**

Answer (score 0):

Quit Cygwin.

Your path to the bin folder of JAVA contains is in another folder named bin ? I don't think so.

Install a JDK (not a JRE) properly in a Path with no blanks. For example : `C:\jdk1.7.0_21`

In Windows :
Add an environnement variable JAVA_HOME to `C:\jdk1.7.0_21`
Then, add the `JAVA_HOME/bin` to your PATH.

Edit hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh : Uncomment the JAVA_HOME Export. For my example :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/jdk1.7.0_21/
```

Comment: thanks but i have resolved issue by my self, it's not just path issue its something other issue from hadoop file. very soon i post my answer